# Check if div is animated and find out the position of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have animated my div element to move to the right side when the 'Sign in' button is clicked.

However when the sign up button is clicked I want the div to move back over to the right.

I just wanted to know if there is any way I could check to see if the div has been animated to the left.

```js
var $width = $("body").width() / 2;;
var $animatedDiv = $(".hero-container");
$("#sign-in").click(function() {
  $animatedDiv = $(".hero-container").animate({
    "left": $width
  }, "slow");

  $("#welcome").html("Sign In");
  $(".form").show();
});

$("#sign-up").click(function() {
  // if the div is on the right, then move it to the left
  if ($animatedDiv.is(':animated')) {
    $animatedDiv = $(".hero-container").animate({
      "right": $width
    }, "slow");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="welcome">
  <div class="hero-container">
    <h1 id="welcome">Welcome!</h1>
    <p>Welcome back</p>
    <button id="sign-in">Sign in</button>
    <button id="sign-up">Sign up</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <form class="sign-in">
      <h1 id="signIn-heading">Sign In</h1>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

If the div is on the right I need to move it to the left when the 'Sign up' button is clicked, therefore the sign up form will display.

Comment: why does it matter?  If the div hasn't moved, animating it won't move it, and if the user clicks "sign in" by accident and then clicks "sign up" then you'll want it to animate back, anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are multiple ways to accomplish your goal. One simple solution is to set a variable once the animation has completed:

```
    var animated_pos = "left";

    var $width =  $("body").width()/2;;
    var $animatedDiv = $(".hero-container");
    $("#sign-in").click(function(){

    $(".hero-container").animate({"left": $width,done:function(){animated_pos = "left";}}, "slow");

    $("#welcome").html("Sign In");

    $(".form").show();

    });

    $("#sign-up").click(function(){

    // if the div is on the right, then move it to the left

    if(animated_pos == "left"){
$(".hero-container").animate({"right": $width,done:function(){animated_pos = "right";}}, "slow");

    }


     });
```